# Proper use of *apply with a function that takes strings as inputs

Tags: string, r

I am interested in applying the `levenshteinSim` function from the **Record-Linkage** package to vectors of strings (there's a good discussion on the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535625/similarity-scores-based-on-string-comparison-in-r) ).

Imagine that I have a vector called `codes`: `"A","B","C","D"`,etc.;
And a vector called `tests`: `"A","B","C","D"`,etc.

Using `sapply` to test a particular value in 'tests' against the vector of `codes`,

```
sapply(codes,levenshteinSim,str2=tests[1])
```

I would expect to get a list or vector (my apologies if I make terminological mistakes): `[score1] [score2] [score3]`.

Unfortunately, the output is a test of the value in `tests[1]` against `c("A","B","C","D", ...)` -- a single value.

Ultimately, I want to `*apply` the two vectors against one another to produce a matrix of length `len1*len2` -- but I don't want to move forward until I understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the problem lies:

```
 library(RecordLinkage)
 sapply(codes,levenshteinSim,str2=test)
     A B C D
[1,] 1 0 0 0
[2,] 0 1 0 0
[3,] 0 0 1 0
[4,] 0 0 0 1
```

When str2 is just one item, you get a length 4 vector.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DWin.  I will have to grab some sample of my data to test things out.  One note: I am "tolower"'ing each element (because levenshteinSim is case sensitive).  I'm not sure how that affects things.