# R: agrep results quantifier

Tags: r, agrep

Is there a built-in way to quantify results of `agrep` function? E.g. in

```
agrep("test", c("tesr", "teqr", "toar"), max = 2, v=T)
[1] "tesr" "teqr"
```

`tesr` is only 1 char permutation away from `test`, while `teqr` is 2, and `toar` is 3 and hence not found. Apparently, `tesr` has higher "probability" than `teqr`. How can it be retrieved either in number of permutations or percentage? 
Thanks!

Edit: Apologies for not putting this in question in first place. I am already running a two-step procedure: `agrep` to get my list, and then `adist` to get N permutations. `adist` is slower, running time is a big factor in my dataset

Comment: Look at the `adist()` function

Comment: @ MrFlick. Yes, I use this one as well, but this means that I need to run 2 functions. Also, `adist` gives N permutations for all possible cases, while I need to limit to `2` in this example

Comment: what is the problem by using two functions?

Comment: So what can't you get out of the `adist` output? Seems like you should be able to use that to subset your vector of interest just as `grep()` does.

Comment: you can use `Filter(function(x) x<=2, adist("test", c("tesr", "teqr", "toar")))`

Comment: Speed is the problem. `agrep` on my data takes 2 seconds per one pattern, and `adist` is a lot slower. I have 40k patterns

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, `Filter...` won't give me the indices or values of those elements that have <= 2 permutations, while this is essential

Comment: if adist is slower why not do it in two steps - agrep, then adist: `words<- data.frame(x=c("tesr", "teqr", "toar")); words$y <- agrepl("test", words$x, 2); ifelse(words$y, adist("test", words$x), NA)`

Comment: @jeremycg, what do you mean? I am already running `agrep` first then `adist`. Doesn't help with running time. Thus inquiring if `agrep` can have some useful output of stats kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Levenshtein distance is the number of edits from one string to another. The package 'RecordLinkage' may be of interest. It provides the edit distance computation below, which should perform [on par with `agrep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535625/similarity-scores-based-on-string-comparison-in-r-edit-distance). Although it will not return the same results as `agrep`.

```
library(RecordLinkage)
ld <- levenshteinDist("test", c("tesr", "teqr", "toar"))
c("tesr", "teqr", "toar")[which(ld < 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can work with that (slightly faster than `adist`) and still do a 2-step process. Pity that `agrep` doesn't have this functionality

Comment: It is two steps but only one computationally intensive function call.

Comment: Yes. First `agrep` is not needed anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `adist()`:

```
s <- c("tesr", "teqr", "toar")
s[adist("test", s) < 3]
```

Or using `stringdist`

```
library(stringdist)
s[stringdist("test", s, method = "lv") < 3]
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "tesr" "teqr"
```

---

**Benchmark**

```
x <- rep(s, 10e5)
library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  levenshteinDist = x[which(levenshteinDist("test", x) < 3)],
  adist = x[adist("test", x) < 3],
  stringdist = x[stringdist("test", x, method = "lv") < 3],
  times = 10
)
```

Which gives:
[image]

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 levenshteinDist  840.7897 1255.1183 1406.8887 1398.4502 1510.5398 1960.4730    10  b 
           adist 2760.7677 2905.5958 2993.9021 2986.1997 3038.7692 3472.7767    10   c
      stringdist  145.8252  155.3228  210.4206  174.5924  294.8686  355.1552    10 a
```

Comment: Thanks. That is another possibility. Will consider as well. Eliminates the need for first `agrep` I suppose

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov If speed is a concern, I would go with `stringdist`

Comment: Ohh! I haven't thought of it, although I was aware that `stringdist` is a lot faster than `agrep`. Just didn't put it together.