# similarity between string rows in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:
[pta corpus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoSOr.png)

Each row of pta_content is the contents of preferential trade agreements. I'm trying to calculate the similarities between each row and obtain a similarity matrix with the name of pta.

I have tried stringdist, it seems that stringdist is used for two dataframes. how can i calculate the pairwise similarities between each row within a dataframe?

Comment: `stringdistmatrix` will do that

Comment: may be just use `dist()`. Also it is always a good idea to share reproducible example. The image doesn't really helps here.

Comment: @RanaUsman dist() can only apply to a numeric matrix or data frame. I have string rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c("abcdefg", "hijklmnop", "qrstuvwxyz")
b <- c("abXdeXg", "hiXklXnoX", "Xrstuvwxyz")

library(RecordLinkage)
levenshteinSim(a, b)
```

**Result**

`[1] 0.7142857 0.6666667 0.9000000`

Since the data is not there, there's not much I can do.

This is taken from [Similarity scores based on string comparison in R (edit distance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535625/similarity-scores-based-on-string-comparison-in-r-edit-distance)