# Partial String Matching in R to unify text into one category

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have dataset as follow

```
EstablishmentName                    Freq
bahria university                    20 
bahria university islamabad          12
arid agriculture                     3
arid agriculture university          15
arid rawalpindi                      9
college of e&me, nust                20
college of e & me (nust)             15
college of eme                       30
```

As you can see above that Bahria University and Bahria University Islamabad are almost same, so goes for other strings. I want to unify them into one such that

**Expected Output**

```
EstablishmentName                   Freq
Bahria University                   32
Arid Agriculture                    27
College of EME                      30
```

I have tried the following solution but it doesn't seems to work.

```
     library(SnowballC)
     library(dplyr)

    mutate(df, word = wordStem(EstablishmentName)) %>%
      group_by(EstablishmentName) %>%
      summarise(total = sum(Freq))
```

Comment: This is not duplicate as clearly the solutions provided there are not working.

Comment: I have updated the post @RonakShah

Comment: I am no expert in this, but I have used the "fuzzyjoin" packages for a similar problem. Might be useful for you aswell.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535625/similarity-scores-based-on-string-comparison-in-r-edit-distance) may help.

Comment: I think you want to group by `word`, not `EstablishmentName`.

Comment: @dmca that doesnt changes results.